# Reading integers from a line

Tags: java

I'm  trying to read two integers on the same line.

```
Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
x=a.nextInt();
y=a.nextInt();
```

Now, if I input

> 3 4
>  3 4

x = 3 and y = 3. I even tried using a.useDelimiter("\\s") but it doesn't work.

Comment: you should use delimeter \\s otherwise it would be an escape character

Comment: Sorry that was a typo... I'm using \\s

Comment: @Buxme: Your code is fine, but perhaps the lines you are reading are not in the format you have indicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be an error elsewhere in your code. It works fine for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = a.nextInt();
        int y = a.nextInt();
        System.out.println("x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
3 4
3 4
```

Output:

```
x = 3, y = 4
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Fiz1n)

Comment: Thanks, Got it working. Actually, I wrapped a.nextInt() inside another function and was calling that function. Removed that wrapper.